# On/Off DC power indicator

Tags: led, power, polarity, indicator

I am pretty sure that this should be simple but the answer is eluding me.

Basically I would like a simple 12V DC circuit that lights one LED (red) when a power switch to a pump is off and would light a second LED (green) when the switch is on.

This seems trivial except that I cannot have the wrong LED illuminated in the wrong condition.

Comment: You don't mention what you actually need help with.  Do you need help designing the whole thing?  Ensuring it is 100% reliable?  What is your current experience level?  Have you ever built anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do if you have dual-pole (SPDT or DPDT) switch. If you do not, a simple relay with normally-closed contact will do the job.

[image: pic]

Edit: updated picture

Comment: An SPDT switch would be simpler - connect the supply to the switch common terminal, red LED to one side, and load and green LED to the other.

Answer (score 1):

- RED = Pump switch on
- GREEN = Pump connected and off
- BOTH OFF = Pump disconnected

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFPAx4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>